# Delete from table on join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to remove all records from table based on the date of another for example I have one table called `pd_course_mstr` that has the following fields

```
course_id
start_dt
```

Then I have another table called `pd_eval_dtl` that has the following fields in it

```
course_id
eval_question
```

The goal is to delete all eval questions that have a particular date. I was able to use SQL to select all the eval questions by using the following statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM pd_eval_dtl AS eval JOIN pd_course_mstr AS course 
    ON eval.course_id = course.course_id 
WHERE course.start_dt='02/17/2014'
```

So I tried to change it to

```
DELETE 
FROM pd_eval_dtl JOIN pd_course_mstr 
    ON pd_eval_dtl.course_id = pd_course_mstr.course_id 
WHERE pd_course_mstr.start_dt='02/17/2014'
```

but it keeps saying I have a syntax error near `JOIN`

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax is

```
DELETE FROM eval
FROM   pd_eval_dtl AS eval
       INNER JOIN pd_course_mstr AS course
         ON eval.course_id = course.course_id
WHERE  ( course.start_dt = '20140217' )
```

Comment: Should be +2 really, 1 for answering correctly first, and 1 for using a culture invariant date format for the string literal date.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I would like to try the other solutions, but this worked, so there is nothing to try them on.

Comment: @GarethD you can borrow mine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DELETE ped
FROM pd_eval_dtl ped 
    INNER JOIN pd_course_mstr pcm ON ped.course_id = pcm.course_id 
WHERE pcm.start_dt='20140217'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM pd_eval_dtl
WHERE EXISTS 
             (SELECT 1 
              FROM pd_course_mstr
              WHERE course_id  = pd_eval_dtl.course_id
              AND start_dt='02/17/2014')
```

Comment: This post could use an explanation to more effectively help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where in`:

```
delete pd_eval_dtl
where  course_id in
       ( select course_id
         from   pd_course_mstr
         where  start_dt='02/17/2014'
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DELETE FROM SECONDTABLE WHERE COURSE_iD IN (SELECT COURSE_iD FROM FIRST TABLE WHERE START_dT IS > REQUIRED DATE)
```